# If you knew the full interacting 2-point correlation function, do you know everything?

Tags: quantum-field-theory, operators, scattering, propagator

I'll specify to the case of a real scalar field to be concrete. If you have some interacting theory with Lagrangian
$$
\mathscr{L}[\phi] = -\tfrac{1}{2} (\partial_{\mu} \phi)(\partial^{\mu} \phi) - \tfrac{1}{2} m^2 \phi^2 + \mathscr{L}_{\mathrm{int}}[\phi]
$$
and let's say hypothetically you magically were able to compute the full interacting 2-point correlation function;
$$
- i G(x;y) \equiv \langle \Omega \big| \mathscr{T}\big( \phi(x) \phi(y) \big) \big| \Omega \rangle
$$
where $\mathscr{T}$ means time-ordering, and $|\Omega\rangle$ denotes the interacting vacuum. (normally you'd write $G$ as a perturbation series over interaction picture field operators evaluated in the *free* vacuum)

Would you be able to compute all the full scattering amplitudes exactly from this (to all orders in couplings)? If so, I imagine it would be something like Fourier transforming combinations of $G$ (to get for example a 2-to-2 scattering matrix element $S_{p_1p_2 \to q_1q_2}$). I think I have heard that this is true before, but I am not sure where to look for this.

Comment: No. Not even in a CFT, which has as much symmetry as you may hope, you can do this. You need also the three-point-function. With less symmetry, which is almost always the case, you need at least as many n-point functions. See also the Wightman reconstruction theorem.